# want to call webelements declared inside a method with args in one class and wanted to call the webele method

Tags: eclipse, selenium

```
package First;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class First1 {
    public static WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    public static WebElement webele;

    public static void LaunchApp(String url){
        driver.get(url);
    }

    public static String webele(String loc){
        webele= driver.findElement(By.id(loc));
        System.out.println("abc");
    }
}

package First;
public class First2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        First1.LaunchApp("https://facebook.com").sendkeys("hdkjasj");
    }
}
```

Here is my next class in the same package to call the method webele with arguments. when trying to call the first class in the second I am getting error as cannot invoke sendkeys(String) into primitive Type void.

Comment: Can you share ypur error message

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you post HTML and/or code please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ or your IDE to properly format everything. If you need help properly formatting it on the site, see the formatting help link in the sidebar of the question editor. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Also post the full error message, properly formatted.